# MongoDB - Getting @DBRef values from list as separate objects

Tags: mongodb, spring-mvc

This is the current object

```
{
"chargeCodeIds" : [
    1,
    2
],
"customChargeCode" : [
    {
        "_id" : 1,
        "chargeCodeType" : "Department",
        "name" : "IT",
        "isBillable" : true,
    },
    {
        "_id" : 2,
        "chargeCodeType" : "Task"
        "name" : "Development",
        "isBillable" : true
    }
]
```

We have the query that searched the charge codes from their collection say "customChargeCode" and listed them in an object "customChargeCode" as array of objects. BUT I don't want it an in array.

Here  is the current query:

```
    db.authorizeChargeAssociation.aggregate([
{
    $project: {
        chargeCodeIds: {
          $map: {
             input: {
                  $map: {
                      input:"$chargeCodes",
                      in: {
                           $arrayElemAt: [{$objectToArray: "$$this"}, 1]
                      },
                  }
             },
             in: "$$this.v"
           }
        },
     }
},

{
    $lookup: {

       from: "customChargeCode",
        localField:"chargeCodeIds",
        foreignField:"_id",
        as:"customChargeCode"
    }
},

{$unwind: {path: "$customChargeCodes", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true} },

],

{ collation: { locale: "en_US", numericOrdering: true}},
{ allowDiskUse: true}
)
```

What I want is to get a separate object of each "chargeCodeIds" from the "customChargeCode" collection and name them the field as "chargeCodeType" value.

Expected Result be like:

```
{
"chargeCodeIds" : [
    1,
    2
],
"Department" : {
        "_id" : 1,
        "chargeCodeType" : "Department",
        "name" : "IT",
        "isBillable" : true,
    },

"Task" :  {
        "_id" : 2,
        "chargeCodeType" : "Task"
        "name" : "Development",
        "isBillable" : true
    }
```